# Send a file over SPI by FT2232HL

Tags: fpga, usb-device, ftdi, sdr

I want to send a bitstream into an fpga with FT2232HL chip. How should i implement sending a file in C to FT2232?

I think about continous transmitting of file, instead of sending it in chunks

Comment: First make sure someone hasn't already published a solution, which they surely have.  Next research what synchronous serial configuration methods your FPGA supports, and what synchronous serial modes the USB chips supports, find a compatible combination, look into what host side libraries are available...

Comment: As you well know, the site is not a free design house or on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work and own findings so far in considerable detail. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract.

Comment: FT2232H datasheet https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT2232H.pdf -- see also https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/MPSSE.htm then scroll down to "USB to SPI Interface using FT2232H"

Answer (score 1):

Given your last question was about configuring a Spartan 6, and you are using an FT2232, take a look at the Papilio Pro board (open source) - that uses the same USB chip and provides a [piece of software](https://github.com/GadgetFactory/Papilio-Loader) to load bitstreams onto a Spartan 6. You should be able to use the same software.